# Isometric and diffeomorphism between the product of $(0, +\infty)$ and $S^{n−1}$ in cylinder $C$

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry

Show that the Riemannian product of $(0, +\infty)$ and $S^{n−1}$ is isometric to the cylinder $C = \{ (x_{0}, \cdots , x_{n}) \in \mathbb{R}^{n+1} | x^{2}_{1} + \cdots+ x^{2}_{n} = 1$ and $x_{0} > 0 \}$.

I am finding this question confusing, since diffeomorphism are applications that preserve compactness. I cannot see that there is an isometry between the cylinder and a sphere, since the sphere is compact and the cylinder is not.

Definition of Isometry. Whether $f:M\to N$ is a diffeomorphism, f is said to be an isometry if the internal product is preserved:

$\langle u, v\rangle_{p} = \langle df(u), df(v)\rangle_{f (p)}$

Comment: You are not looking for an isometry to a sphere, but to a product of a sphere with an open - so non-compact - interval.

Comment: Yeah, do can you help me? please.

Comment: If you are taking a course in which this is an exercise, you should be able to do better on your own. Start by writing down the obvious diffeomorphism.

Comment: Yeah, first, I must prove the diffeomorphism, I can do that, my difficulty is to show the isometry.

Comment: Well, edit your question to include the diffeomorphism and your attempts to check it's an isometry. This is not a difficult problem. (Start with $n=2$ and draw the picture.)

Comment: There, I edited it. Do you can help me? I really want to learn this.

Comment: You have not added any mathematics at all. What is the diffeomorphism?

Comment: What is a diffeomrphism I know. This I can prove, I mean to prove isometry.